# Parsing CDATA from XML in DXL

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, ibm-doors

I'm building an XML parser for a tool I'm working on in DOORs Extension Language and I am running into an issue parsing the  information.

I've been using this group of functions to parse the XML and so far everything has been working just fine:

```
DOM_Document_ getDocumentBuffer_ (DOM_Document_, Buffer&)
string getStringAttribute_ (DOM_Element_, string)
string getElementName_ (DOM_Element_)
string setStringAttribute_ (DOM_Element_, string, string)
void ::do (DOM_Element_&, DOM_Element_, void)
void ::do (DOM_Element_&, DOM_Element_, void)
bool hasAttribute_ (DOM_Element_, string)
bool hasChildElements_ (DOM_Element_)
DOM_Element_ getDocumentElement_ (DOM_Document_)
string getElementText_ (DOM_Element_)
DOM_Document_ parseXMLBuffer_ (Buffer)
DOM_Document_ parseXMLString_ (string)
```

Althought, when I get to a CDATA block, I start to run into issues. I assume I would be able to use the getElementText_(DOM_Document_) method to get the nested text but that returns nothing.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Here's the XML snippet that I'm working with:

```
     <xmlTag
        att = "a"
        btt = "b"
        ctt = "c" >
        <![CDATA[...]]>
     </xmlTag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another library to solve the issue that handles CDATA parsing: https://github.com/domoran/dxlstdlib